# Why does my row duplicate deleter freeze

Tags: arrays, vba

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lastUsedRowDiff As Long
    Dim lastUsedColumnDiff As Long
    Dim myWrkbook As Workbook
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim columnArray() As Integer
    Dim p As Integer

    lastUsedRowDiff = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lastUsedColumnDiff = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ReDim columnArray(1 To lastUsedColumnDiff)
    For p = 1 To lastUsedColumnDiff
        p = columnArray(p)
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastUsedRowDiff,               lastUsedColumnDiff)).RemoveDuplicates _
    Columns:=Array(columnArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the debugger to find where it freezes (or loops indefinitely). F8 lets you execute the code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I have probably written more than just support advice, but it is intended as an education on this topic. Please read right to the end as there is important information about 'RemoveDuplicates'.

I have commented throughout your code to explain what I am seeing happening. The answer to the core question 'why does it freeze' is because you have an infinite loop.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lastUsedRowDiff As Long
    Dim lastUsedColumnDiff As Long
    Dim myWrkbook As Workbook
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim columnArray() As Integer
    Dim p As Integer

    'If you are finding the last used row and col you should also find the 
    'first used row as it may not always be 1
    'Dim LngFirstUsedCol     As Long
    'Dim LngFirstUsedRow     As Long
    'LngFirstUsedCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column
    'LngFirstUsedRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row

    'If this is for the row, it should take .Rows.count, not 'Columns.Count
    'lastUsedRowDiff = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastUsedRowDiff = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lastUsedColumnDiff = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Also, the title of your varible refers to the difference but later they 
    'are used as the actual address
    'i.e. I have a range that has 1 column in it, but it is on column E (5), 
    'your code would return 1 which is right as I only have 1 column, but 
    'when using that as an address if refers to column A (1) which is not 
    'right We would need the address to be roughly: -
    ''First Used Column' + 'Used Column Count'

    'I am assuming this is trying to build an array of all the columns?
    'But is saying:-
    '   From P (which starts at 1) to the number of the last used column
    '       set P to 0
    '   Move to the next P (i.e. Increment it to back up to 1)
    'This is why you are stuck in a loop, turning them around would get past 
    'the issue to an extent
    ReDim columnArray(1 To lastUsedColumnDiff)
    For p = 1 To lastUsedColumnDiff
        p = columnArray(p)
        'columnArray(p) = p
    Next

    'The above code looks to include every column, by simply omitting the 
    ''Columns' parameter from the 'RemoveDuplicates' function, it would by 
    'default select all columns, so you could remove the For loop too
    'You did not need to place 'Array' around your array as it is already 
    'an array
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastUsedRowDiff, lastUsedColumnDiff)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(columnArray)
    'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastUsedRowDiff, lastUsedColumnDiff)).RemoveDuplicates

    'In addition to the above, you should used the first row and column as 
    'well and not assume it is A1 (Cells(1,1))
    'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(LngFirstUsedRow, LngFirstUsedCol), Cells(lastUsedRowDiff, lastUsedColumnDiff)).RemoveDuplicates

    'Finally as mentioned prior, you are using the difference as the address 
    'in error
    'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(LngFirstUsedRow, LngFirstUsedCol), Cells(LngFirstUsedRow + (lastUsedRowDiff - 1), LngFirstUsedCol + (lastUsedColumnDiff))).RemoveDuplicates

    'Orrrr this whole proc can be reduced to a single line of three words
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates

End Sub
```

Finally, and this is important, Read what [Richard Michaels](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/9584db0f-f35b-4a4f-9e98-43083c0dd786#user-profile-tab-profile) has to say about RemoveDuplicates in [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/removeduplicates-macro/4f8a1b78-8848-4fa7-835f-4bfc7100e3b8?auth=1). Basically, in VBA it is not a safe function, I would recommend manually writing code that removes duplicates or ensuring it stays within the safe parameters of a single column range and not passing the `Columns` variable.

Comment: it doesnt work, it froze again. Im just gonna use advanced filter or something